# Anchor not working in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My question is a little odd and silly

When i try to use an anchor in my blade file i confront with below issue:

If i click on the link that is supposed to be an anchor, in browser address Bar i get wrong address. for example

```
<a href="#child">Test-1</a>
<a href="#mother">Test-2</a>
<a href="#father">Test-3</a>

<div id="child">
    Test-1
</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<div id="mother">
    Test-2
</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="father">
    Test-3
</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

When i click on any of the above three links browser address changes to **current-page/#!#child** instead of **current-page/#child**

Does anyone had this issue?

Comment: Can you try remove your blade file and create it again? No problem at all on my pc. I tried it on my pc. It worked.

Comment: Yes, me too. Its working for me. Also try it in different browser after clearing the \cache..

Comment: I tried all the above, still the same problem. also i removed all js in my blade.

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework like Vue or Angular?

Comment: Yes angular is used in some parts of the system.

Comment: Is angularjs included in the scripts present in this page? If yes, angular is trying to route your anchors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eddy. angular was manipulating my anchors.